# Update price according to the quantity HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function modPrice() {
  var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  var total = price * quantity;
  price = total;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<div id="price">25</div>
<button onclick="readDescription()" id="minfo">More Description</button><br>
<div id="moreinfo">
  enter
  <h6>Description: Vanilla Cake with Figs, Healthy Cake for any celebration!</h6>
  <h6>Storage: Shelf</h6>
  <h6>Product #: 987-063</h6>
</div><br>
<label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
<input type="number" id="quantity" value="quantity" name="quantity" onclick="modPrice()" min="1">
<br>
<button id="additem" data-name="cake" data-price="25" onclick="addItem()"> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> ADD TO CART </button>
```

my goal is to change the value in the div price accordingly to the quantity. The error that I'm having is that it shows NAN in the div after changing the quantity.

Comment: You cannot get the content of a div with the `value` attribute, use `innerText` instead. You should also check that it is a number before using it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not use `.value`  to retrieve text of a div, use `.innerText` for example.
2. You have a typo: `id="minfo>`
3. Do not use `value` as a placeholder for input, there is literary a `placeholder` HTML attribute...
4. With  `innerText` you will retrieve a string not a number. You need to convert it to do math with it, I used here [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for integer numbers.
5. Do not use on click, that will react only when when clicked on input not on change of value or input itself. Use `oninput` [event or something else](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

```js
function modPrice() {
  var price = document.getElementById("price").innerText;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  var total = parseInt(price) * quantity;
  console.log(total)
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<div id="price">25</div>
<button onclick="readDescription()" id="minfo">More Description</button><br>
<div id="moreinfo">
  enter
  <h6>Description: Vanilla Cake with Figs, Healthy Cake for any celebration!</h6>
  <h6>Storage: Shelf</h6>
  <h6>Product #: 987-063</h6>
</div><br>
<label for="quantity ">Quantity:</label>
<input type="number " id="quantity" placeholder="quantity " name="quantity " oninput="modPrice() " min="1 ">
<br>
<button id="additem " data-name="cake " data-price="25 " onclick="addItem() "> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart "></i> ADD TO CART </button>
```

Also please learn how to use `console.log()` to test every step of your code...